# MapvView v2 in a Listview

Tags: android, google-maps, listview, dictionary

Hy, I am trying to implement a MapView into a ListView, but it won´t work properly. Though the map is displayed, i can not move the camera programmatically, add any Marker Objects and the UI MyLocation Button is also not there. (I initialized everything in the getView Method of the adapter. I hope anybody knows the Problem and can help.) Thanks in adavance .

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View listenEintrag = null;
        if (position == 0) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            listenEintrag = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details_head,
                    parent, false);

            mMapView = (MapView) listenEintrag
                    .findViewById(R.id.mv_karteAnzeigen);
            mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
            options.position(valueSpiel.getOrt().getPosition());
            options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));

            try {
                initMapView();
                mMapView.onResume();
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }...
```

with the initMapView Method:

```
private void initMapView()
            throws GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException {
        boolean usePlayService = isGooglePlayServiceAvailable();
        if (usePlayService) {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getApplicationContext());

            if (map == null) {
                map = mMapView.getMap();
                if (map != null) {
                    map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
                    map.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
                    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
                    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(17.5f));

                }
            }
        } else {
            ((Activity) getApplicationContext()).finish();
        }
    }

    private boolean isGooglePlayServiceAvailable() {
        int errorCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
        if (errorCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            Dialog errorDialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(
                    errorCode, (Activity) getApplicationContext(), -1);
            if (errorDialog != null) {
                errorDialog.show();
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: This is a bad idea in general, try using a viewpager to host your maps instead.

Comment: But with a ViewPager I can´t create a List, can I ?
I thought it is just for left-right swips, for Example für Action Bar based Tabs?